# Swift Xcode 9.4 Frameworks

Tags: xcode, frameworks, avfoundation

I am currently stuck on an error I have come across in the latest version of Xcode. I had just released a new update for my latest game. However, it was rejected as the game didn't start up on the device. I have looked into the problem but I don't know how to solve it. If anyone has any suggestions, please let me know.

> objc[2742]: Class VCWeakObjectHolder is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AVConference.framework/Frameworks/ViceroyTrace.framework/ViceroyTrace (0x128bca4d0) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AVConference.framework/AVConference (0x128a4ae38). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it was rejected because of the framework issue? I'd like to know because I have the same issue with my project but it does not come up as an error and it works fine on my device.

Anyway this question was dealt with before. Search for this - "Multiple classes in frameworks warning"